# Why does bluetoothd show version 5.37 after installing Bluez 5.45?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, bluez

I have downloaded and unpacked Bluez 5.45.
I successfully ran

```
./configure
make
make install
```

And I restarted my machine.

```
bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]#version
```

Gives me `Version 5.45`, however

```
bluetoothd -v
```

Gives me `5.37`.

Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the contents](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/bluez/filelist) of the [bluez package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bluez) you'll note that `bluetoothd` and `bluetoothctl` are seperate programs, not to be confused with the version of the package. It's not uncommon for a collection for programs in a package to have their own separate versions. In order to insure that you aren't using an out pf date version of one of the aforementioned programs you could use `which` to insure that you are launching the one that you installed by checking the location against the file list shown in the first link that I provided. You'll see that `which bluetoothd` should respond with `/usr/sbin` and `which bluetoothctl` should respond with `/usr/bin/` if you get those results odds are good that nothing is wrong. *Unless you've used a PPA or installed bluez by compiling it yourself, in which case your question requires further detail.*